# router.navigateByUrl don't send value Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying send 1 value between components Angular ... but when I arrive in my component I don't receive nothing.

Component1:

```
onCellClicked(event) {
    if (event.colDef.field === 'dni') {
      console.log('dni en mi componente : ', event.value);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('probarborrar/', event.value);
    }
  }
```

First check if the Cell is dni, then I show `"console.log(event.value)"` It is true, I can see my dni. Finally I go the second component.

Routing.

```
     {
        path: 'probarborrar/:idUser',
        component: ProbandoBorrarComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'probar'
        }
      }
```

Component2.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-probando-borrar',
  templateUrl: './probando-borrar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./probando-borrar.component.scss']
})
export class ProbandoBorrarComponent implements OnInit {
  public dni;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dni= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('idUser');
    console.log('en probando es :', this.dni); -->nothing
  }
}
```

html

```
<p style="color:white;background-color:black;">
  probando-borrar works! : {{ dni }}
</p>
```

I can arrive Component2 but I don't receive nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using the [navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) function for this. Apparently `navigateByUrl` has an [issue with queryParams](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18798#issuecomment-386065087).
Secondly, you need to pass a [navigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#navigationextras) object to the `navigate` function.

Checkout the code sample.

```
this.router.navigate(['probarborrar'], {queryParams: {idUser: event.value}});
```

In component2, retrieve the value like

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      console.log(params['idUser']);
  });
}
```

Working Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytfgp8

Comment: console.log(params['idUser']);  undefined

Comment: @EduBw seems like the [problem is with navigateByUrl](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18798#issuecomment-386065087). You should be using the [navigate function](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) instead. I have updated my code sample and also added a demo for you to check out.

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'probarborrar'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'probarborrar'

Comment: Create a route for your component2. It's all demonstrated in the demo.

Comment: Oks, perfect I see my error, very thanks, other question I can't hide idUser the URL ???

Comment: @EduBw I think you would have to use a service for that: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8515#issuecomment-241216641

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`;

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dni = this.route
      .queryParamMap
      .pipe(map((params) => {
        const param = params.get('idUser');
        console.log(param);
        return param;
      }
      ));
  }
```

Read more about **routing and naviagtion** in [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments).

Comment: It don't find name map .pipe(map(...)

Comment: Did you import the **map** from **rxjs/operators** ?

Comment: Yes, now I import map result in html  :  [object Object]

Comment: console.log the output and see. Or you can use a json pipe to print it on the html {{ result | json}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171681/discussion-between-anuradha-gunasekara-and-edubw).